# Can I boot off of a .vdi file?

Tags: installation, windows, virtualbox, migration

I am using windows 7 as a host & have ubuntu vdi file. Which I created using Virtual Box & installed the Ubuntu OS in ubuntu.vdi file. Now I want to boot Ubuntu Directly on my hardware. that is at booting time of my pc I could see an option to boot win 7 & Ubuntu. Just want to boot Ubuntu.vdi as real machine. Please help me out.

Answer (score 5):

You are IMO better off doing a fresh, standard installation. I do not know an easy way to directly boot your ubuntu.vdi, you could probably copy the partition with dd or gparted, but you would then need to manually install and configure grub.

Installing will do the configuration for you, and is thus going to be easier.

You can back up your user data (home) to a usb drive or transfer it from vitrualbox with the use of  shared folders.

You can generate a list of installed packages with

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections > packages.list
```

You then transfer packages.list to your fresh install and use it to restore you packages with

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < packages.list
sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

Comment: +1 this is the only sensible way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can, as long as the disk image is a fixed size image. You are a lot better of just doing a new install of Ubuntu, and then mounting the .vdi file by opening it in Virtualbox or with Archive Mounter and then copying your files over. But, if you really want to and are willing to spend enough time at it, here is a tutorial on how to do so. http://wiki.przemoc.net/tips/linux#mounting_partition_from_vdi_fixed-size_image Also see: http://srackham.wordpress.com/cloning-and-copying-virtualbox-virtual-machines/