# Create a Linux partition which can be used from Virtual Box or booted into natively

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I looking for a way to use ubuntu inside of a Virtualbox and then boot natively into the same OS for doing more intensive tasks.

I'm aware this is support under windows, but obviously I'm looking for a ubuntu equivelent.

I've looked in booting from .vdi and .vmdk but neither seem to support natively booting from them.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/495025/use-physical-harddisk-in-virtual-box

Comment: indeed! I'll change to dup

Comment: You can backup your home from the ,VDI and put it on a fresh Ubuntu install and install the same program packages.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/94408/can-i-boot-off-of-a-vdi-file